# Converting old Swift in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I often come across old GitHub code of interest and play around with it. If this is Swift, there is the possibility it is in Swift 2 format. These will no longer open in modern Xcode.

To solve this problem I kept a copy of Xcode 10.1 on my machine, as it contained a converter that worked very well. I just noticed that 10.1 will no longer run under Monterey.

Is there some way to run conversions of old Swift in new Xcode?

Comment: What does *old* mean? There are significant changes from Swift 2 to 3 but it's not that hard to convert Swift 3 → Swift 4 → Swift 5 manually and you will learn a lot about the language.

Comment: What does "run conversions" mean? If you can't use an older computer or an emulated older system, just rebuild the project from scratch and fix the compiler issues yourself.

Comment: Swift 2 mostly, question updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify swift language version in xcode -> target -> build settings -> Swift language version.The oldest one is swift 4.0 on my 13.4 xcode. If it's older version i think updating Swift syntax by yourself will be the best choice